# meta query condition don't work

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query, meta-query

I have created a custom post type (Event). I want to show only two posts on the front page and the post should be greater than or equal to today's date. So I write this meta_query.

```
$today = date('ymd');
      $homePostEvents = new WP_Query(array(
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'post_type' => 'event',
        'meta_key' => 'event_date',
        'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
        'order' => 'ASC',
        'meta_query' => array(
          array(
            'key' => 'event_date',
            'compare' => '>=',
            'value' => $today, // Today,
            'type' => 'NUMERIC'
          )
        )
      ));
```

So the outcome should be the future date event post but it also bring up the previous date post too.
[image]

Comment: In what format are your dates stored?

Comment: Ymd format.....

Answer (score 0):

Can you try changing `'type' => 'NUMERIC'` to `'type' => 'DATE'` ?

Reference: https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Meta_Query